# Excluding part of a message from being sent to txt file

Tags: php

I have a script that I wrote that pretty much emails form data and sends it to a txt file. My question is how do I exclude some of the message from being sent to the text file? I don't want to send to the text file this  line :

```
$message .= "A quote will be forwarded to 
Joe Greeninger before order is placed.\n";
```

please help! How?

```
<?php
//$silver_name_badges = !empty($_POST['silver_name_badges']) ? ($_POST['silver_name_badges'])) : false;
$SilverNameBadges = $_POST['Silver_Name_Badges'];
$CoffeeMug = $_POST['Coffee_Mug'];
$Plastic_Literature_Bag = $_POST['Plastic_Literature_Bag'];
$Amada_Bag = $_POST['Amada_bag'];
$Candy = $_POST['Candy'];
$Moist_Towlette = $_POST['Moist_Towlette'];
$Notepad_and_Pen = $_POST['Notepad_and_Pen'];
$Tuck_Box = $_POST['Tuck_Box'];
$Amada_Tie = $_POST['Amada_Tie'];
$Cap = $_POST['Cap'];
$name = $_POST['Attention_To'];
$Red_Lanyard = $_POST['Red_Lanyard'];
$White_Lanyard = $_POST['White_Lanyard'];
$Green_Lanyard = $_POST['Green_Lanyard'];
$Black_Lanyard = $_POST['Black_Lanyard'];
$Glass_LC2415_NT = $_POST['Glass_LC2415_NT'];
$Glass_FOM2NTRI = $_POST['Glass_FOM2NTRI'];
$Glass_ASTRO_165WNT = $_POST['Glass_ASTRO_165WNT'];
$Glass_FOL_AJ3015 = $_POST['Glass_FOL_AJ3015'];
$Glass_ACIES_NT = $_POST['Glass_ACIES_NT'];
$Notes = $_POST['Notes'];
$Ship_Preference = $_POST['Ship_Preference'];



// Please specify your Mail Server - Example: mail.yourdomain.com.
ini_set("SMTP","mail.amada-america.com");

// Please specify an SMTP Number 25 and 8889 are valid SMTP Ports.
ini_set("smtp_port","25");

// Please specify the return address to use
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'jgreeninger@amada.com');

// Set parameters of the email
$to = "ravila@amada.com";
$subject = "Amada Promo Items Ordered";
$from = " jgreeninger@amada.com";
$headers = "CC: ravila@amada.com";


$message = "";
$message .= date("m-d-Y\n");
$message .= "Order has been placed.  
Items:\n";
foreach ($_POST as $fieldName => $fieldValue){
    if (!empty($fieldValue))
        $message .= "   $fieldName: $fieldValue\n";
}
$message .= "A quote will be forwarded to 
Joe Greeninger before order is placed.\n";
$message = str_replace("_"," ",$message);


// Mail function that sends the email.
mail($to,$subject,$message,$footer,$headers);

$fp = fopen("latc.txt", "a");
fwrite($fp, $message."\r\n");
fclose($fp); 
  header('Location: index.html');

?>
```

Comment: crazy question! how is it possible to fail on this "problem"?

Comment: You could always delete it? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the order of things so you write the file before adding that line to the message:

```
foreach ($_POST as $fieldName => $fieldValue){
    if (!empty($fieldValue))
        $message .= "   $fieldName: $fieldValue\n";
}
$message = str_replace("_"," ",$message);

$fp = fopen("latc.txt", "a");
fwrite($fp, $message."\r\n");
fclose($fp); 

$message .= "A quote will be forwarded to 
Joe Greeninger before order is placed.\n";


// Mail function that sends the email.
mail($to,$subject,$message,$footer,$headers);
```

Comment: duh!!! Thanks. I'm a noob btw. Ultra noob!

Comment: How would i make the $message .= "A quote will be forwarded to 
Joe Greeninger before order is placed.\n"; come out in the color red in the email?

Comment: You need to add a `Content-type: text/html` header, and then do `$message .= "<span style='color: red'>A quote will be forwarded to Joe Greeninger before order is placed.</span><br>\n";`. You'll have to change the rest of the message to HTML as well.

Comment: hahaha. This worked but now it doesn't write anything to the txt file. What i'm i doing wrong. I want it to write evrythin to the email except this red text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
//$silver_name_badges = !empty($_POST['silver_name_badges']) ? ($_POST['silver_name_badges'])) : false;
$SilverNameBadges = $_POST['Silver_Name_Badges'];
$CoffeeMug = $_POST['Coffee_Mug'];
$Plastic_Literature_Bag = $_POST['Plastic_Literature_Bag'];
$Amada_Bag = $_POST['Amada_bag'];
$Candy = $_POST['Candy'];
$Moist_Towlette = $_POST['Moist_Towlette'];
$Notepad_and_Pen = $_POST['Notepad_and_Pen'];
$Tuck_Box = $_POST['Tuck_Box'];
$Amada_Tie = $_POST['Amada_Tie'];
$Cap = $_POST['Cap'];
$name = $_POST['Attention_To'];
$Red_Lanyard = $_POST['Red_Lanyard'];
$White_Lanyard = $_POST['White_Lanyard'];
$Green_Lanyard = $_POST['Green_Lanyard'];
$Black_Lanyard = $_POST['Black_Lanyard'];
$Glass_LC2415_NT = $_POST['Glass_LC2415_NT'];
$Glass_FOM2NTRI = $_POST['Glass_FOM2NTRI'];
$Glass_ASTRO_165WNT = $_POST['Glass_ASTRO_165WNT'];
$Glass_FOL_AJ3015 = $_POST['Glass_FOL_AJ3015'];
$Glass_ACIES_NT = $_POST['Glass_ACIES_NT'];
$Notes = $_POST['Notes'];
$Ship_Preference = $_POST['Ship_Preference'];



// Please specify your Mail Server - Example: mail.yourdomain.com.
ini_set("SMTP","mail.amada-america.com");

// Please specify an SMTP Number 25 and 8889 are valid SMTP Ports.
ini_set("smtp_port","25");

// Please specify the return address to use
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'jgreeninger@amada.com');

// Set parameters of the email
$to = "ravila@amada.com";
$subject = "Amada Promo Items Ordered";
$from = " jgreeninger@amada.com";
$headers = "CC: ravila@amada.com";


$message = "";
$message .= date("m-d-Y\n");
$message .= "Order has been placed.  
Items:\n";
foreach ($_POST as $fieldName => $fieldValue){
    if (!empty($fieldValue))
        $message .= "   $fieldName: $fieldValue\n";
}

$message = str_replace("_"," ",$message);


// Mail function that sends the email.
$mailMsg = $message . " A quote will be forwarded to Joe Greeninger before order is placed.\n";
mail($to,$subject,$mailMsg,$footer,$headers);

$fp = fopen("latc.txt", "a");
fwrite($fp, $message."\r\n");
fclose($fp); 
  header('Location: index.html');
?>
```